Is there any literal meaning of 'put out' from which the meaning of willingness of a woman to have sex is derived?
Of many meanings of 'put out', I see that it has (North American English, slang) to agree to have sex with somebody in intransitive verb form.
What physical action that the phrase 'put out' describes led to have that meaning? Is it from the action of lying down and have her body ready for the sex?  Or did it take on that meaning without any reference to implied literal meaning?  Also, is it always used with a woman?
Thank you.

https://www.etymonline.com/word/put-out#:~:text=The%20verbal%20phrase%20is%20from,sex%22%20is%20attested%20by%201947.

That's a misleading definition. To say that "she puts out" means not that she "agrees" to have sex but that  "she is promiscuous", though the speakers who use the phrase "to put out" in that way would likely not know what the word "promiscuous" means.

Thank you Lambie, TimR for the comments.  The link does not seem to give any help in understanding the phase.

Strong advice:  Don't use this kind of sexist language. It's nearly always applied to women by misogenists.
No need to over analyse this.  "Out" has the sense of "being available"; if something is "out" it is "in the open", "visible to outsiders" and so can be easily taken".
So a woman who "puts out" makes herself (physically) available to men.

Thank you James very much for the answer and the advice.  I would not use this type phrase myself, but I need to understand when it is said in a movie or drama.  There are so many phrases or words that mean making-love, and many of them are euphemistic like "someone is good in the sack", it helps to remember and understand better if I know the origin of the meaning.  So, the out means "14.  available to everyone; known to everyone"  as defined in https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/out_1

We have similar phrase or verb that means the same thing describing a woman in my native language. The combo of adverbs like 'out' and easy verbs like go, get, put, make, take, etc. are hard to get a good and complete grasp of for non-native speakers like me. Thank you,
